# How to validate a entry for only non-integer values in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to know can we validate a entry  for string values only. Means you can't put any integer into the string. I know we can do similar one where we can disable entering the alphabetic values for a entry like this:

```
def only_numbers(char):
    return char.isdigit()

validation = parent.register(only_numbers)
entry = Entry(parent, validate="key", validatecommand=(validation, '%S'))
```

but, is there any similar way to disable non integer or alphabetic values from entering.

Comment: `return not char.isalnum()` to enable only special character `return char.isalnum()` allows only characters and numeric values

Comment: is there any way to disable special characters aswell

Comment: Read that again `return char.isalnum()` will allow only alphabets and numbers. which means that it will exclude special characters.

Comment: yeah but I don't want alphabets and special characters. Thanks for replying

Comment: Does that mean you only want numbers?

Comment: I am sorry. I got confused... i want only alphabets no special characters

Comment: `return char.isalpha()`

Comment: Thank you very much. You should have answered it maybe tho maybe someone also have a similar question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JacksonPRO for answering

```
def only_numbers(char):
    return char.isalpha()

validation = parent.register(only_alphabet)
entry = Entry(parent, validate="key", validatecommand=(validation, '%S'))
```